# Drupal node?destination not working

Tags: drupal

I've troubles with Drupal 6 and (maybe) mod_rewrite:

if I go to *http://127.0.0.1/drupal/node/115/edit?destination=admin%2Fcontent%2Fnode* and then I save the node, I don't get redirected to *admin/content/node*, but it directs me to node/115 :-(

Why??

In my .htaccess I uncommented: *RewriteBase /drupal* (because my drupal path is /var/www/htdocs/drupal)

My server is running Apache 2.2.4 on Slackware 12

Any help I'll be appreciated :D

Comment: something is wrong with your configuration .. what do you see when you go to `http://localhost/drupal/admin` ? -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does look like a configuration problem, because this normally works. You can debug it by adding some dsm() dumps in `includes/common.inc/drupal_goto()` : this is where the `destination` parameter is processed.

Note that if some module traps your form submission, for instance by declaring a `_validate` or `_submit` handler, it can very well change the redirection information: check whether you can reproduce this without contrib modules enabled.

Comment: thank you very much, it was a module issue: "Login destination"